# Does anyone have a kindle?

Tags: release-loki

I want to by an amazon kindle paperwhite 2015 and I'm not sure it will work fine. Does anyone have one, can you connect it and upload pdfs or mobis on it without problems? I've searched the ubuntu forums, but I could not find a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a kindle, the last model that came out. The basic one, not the paperwhite, and it works well.

You have 2 options to manage your library:

A) You can plug your kindle like any other USB and copy/paste your files inside the documents folder of the kindle.

B) You can install [`calibre`](https://calibre-ebook.com/), an ebook manager that let's you convert books to a different format, edit metadata and organize your library.